# Trying to submit to email address in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have built an app which displays a quiz and then provides a score at the end. I want the app to also submit that score to an email address. But cannot find any resources which enable me to do this?

Comment: I guess you haven't read about  [ActionMailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), the mailer component of Rails.

Comment: See http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails